# GCM Push Delayed from Amazon SNS Server; immediate push from SNS Management Admin

Tags: java, grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

My problem is that pushes coming from my local serve to SNS are not delivered to a device until a push is made from the SNS Management Console. 
The push from my Java server to SNS using the Java API seem to be "stuck" until I create a test push in the console. When this is done, all messages I have sent from my server to the SNS get sent along in a batch.

I've setup an App using GCM in the SNS Management Console. Adding to it step by step to make sure everything appears correct. The GCM setup (Server API Key, etc) look correct.
I've created an App and it runs. Gets the RegId from Google. And the GcmIntents are setup correctly. I then create an Endpoint in the Management Console with the RegId. I can Publish to this endpoint and they appear on the device. Excellent.
In my Java server I'll programmatically create this Endpoint, send this to the SNS and then Publish to it. I receive a MessageId and it all looks good. But the message will not be delivered to the device. I can do this multiple times. Everything looks correct.

To test my sanity, I go back to the Management console and I can see that the Endpoint is created and is ready. I use the Publish button to send a test message ("asddsaasd") and it is sent to the device. But all my previous messages are **also sent**. It looks like they are stuck in a queue that is only processed until the Management Console Publish button is used.

I can see no differences between the messages sent from my server or from the Console (as received by the ADB). Setting different values for the parameters or removing from my Java server makes no difference.

What am I missing?
My Java server is nothing special. Grails/Groovy project with the "aws-sdk:1.7.4" being used. Nothing else.

Thanks in advance for any tips.